# How to go back to the previous screen in single time backbutton pressed and how to exit from application while back button pressed twice?

Tags: android, exit, onbackpressed

I want to perform an operation like when i pressed back Button single time then it will move to the selected screen and when i pressed twice Back Button  then it will show the dialog and ask for exit.

I tried many examples in stack overflow but none of them are helping me..

**navaigation.java**

```
    private int clickCount = 0;
    private long delay = 100;
    Timer timer = new Timer();

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (clickCount == 2) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            timer.cancel();
        } else{
            clickCount++;
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            backButtonHandler();
                        }
                    });
                }

        }, delay);
    }

}




public void backButtonHandler() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
            Navigation.this);
    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("Leave application?");
    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to leave the application?");
    // Setting Icon to Dialog
    alertDialog.setIcon(R.drawable.m_visit);
    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // Write your code here to invoke NO event
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

I tried this way but it is not working properly...

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: there are so many answer still you are not able to resolve your issues and all the answers are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final int TIME_DELAY = 2000;
private static long back_pressed;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (back_pressed + TIME_DELAY > System.currentTimeMillis()) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } 
    else {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure, You wanted to exit");
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("yes", 
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
          finish();
        }
       });

        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("No",new
       DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dismiss();
         }
       });

       AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
       alertDialog.show();
      }    
    }
    back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
}
```

Comment: i want to use dialog for exit it will ask me to exit when i apply your code then it will display the dailog in single click and when i click twice it will directly exited from the application

Comment: @Sachin check answer.

Comment: it is working for only exit but i want like if i click single time then it will move to the selected screen.

Comment: and i put the fragment also in the if  condition for moving to the another screen

Comment: if u will back press, it will move to screen,

Comment: try using `<` sign for if condition.

Answer (score 0):

Hey check this code I have showed Snackbar if user clicks the back button for the first time.And for second time Application will get exit.

```
private boolean mIsBackAlreadyPressed;

    @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else if (mIsBackAlreadyPressed) {
            mIsBackAlreadyPressed = false;
            super.onBackPressed();
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_left, R.anim.push_out_right);
        } else {
            mIsBackAlreadyPressed = true;
            Snackbar.make(drawer, R.string.press_back_twice, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mIsBackAlreadyPressed = false;
                }
            }, 2000);
        }
    }
```

Hope this help.Happy coding.

Comment: if user pressed single time then it will move to the next screen? how can i apply this/

Comment: @Sachin can you please tell what you want exactly.A and B activity are there is user is on B activity and clicks back button will go to A activity if user clicks back button from B activity  2 times then application will exit.This is what you want?

Comment: yes exactly... and when user click back button two times it will display the dialog and ask me to exit

Comment: @Sachin in my code instead of Snackbar use the dialog to exit the Application.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
 private boolean exit=false;//declare in public

public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (exit) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Tap again to exit.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        exit = true;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                exit = false;
            }
        }, 3 * 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is exit in this?

Comment: private Boolean exit = false;

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    private Boolean close_app = false;
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (close_app) {
            //finish(); // pressed twice
            backButtonHandler();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back again to Exit.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            close_app = true;
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    close_app = false;
                }
            }, 3 * 1000);
        }
    }
```

The `Handler` here handles back presses, it simply shows a `Toast`, and if there is another back press within 3 seconds, it shows the dialog for exiting the application

Answer (score 0):

*if you press back then u can go where ever u want*

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Exit.this,Home.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

*If u double click back button now u can exit try below code*

```
private Boolean exit = false;
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (exit) {
        finish(); // finish activity
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press Back again to Exit.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        exit = true;
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                exit = false;
            }
        }, 3 * 1000);

    }

}
```

Comment: should i paste this code in every fragment activity? for press back single time?

Comment: u have to pass this on  that where u call all the fragments(Activity Screen) u can paste this code